# Problem with Drawing graph with xymatrix

Tags: graphs, xymatrix

I have a problem that i can't manage. Multiple errors with a same line. What to do with that? Below is also a graph that it is supposed to draw, but don't really know why it doesn't compile. Please help me...

[image]

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Please help us help you and add a minimal working example  [(MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that), starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}` (including only relevant packages) that still illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To start I'd like to ask you that you `implement` code in your posts. It makes it much easier for us. Like so:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\begin{document}
Hello world!
\end{document}
```

You achieve such result by adding four spaces before each additional line of the code. You can also suggest that a certain portion of text is code by adding this particular text between `` (you get these symbols by pressing `alt gr+7`). Like `so`.

So without further a do, let's get started.
The first problem I see is that you are using `xymatrix`. I suggest you to hop onto `tikzcd`, at least for less complex graphs and commutative diagrams.

Your desired code with `tikzcd` would look like this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{tikzcd}
& & & (0{,}4) \\
& & B \arrow[ru, "B^{1}_{1}"]  \arrow[rd, "B^{1}_{2}"]& \\
& & & (5{,}1) \\
& & & \\
& & & (0{,}3) \\
A \arrow[rruuuu, "A_{1}"] \arrow[rrdddd, "A_{3}"] \arrow[rr, "A_{2}"] & & B \arrow[ru, "B_{1}"] \arrow[rd, "B_{2}"] \\
& & & (-2{,}4) \\
& & & \\
& & & (4{,}-2) \\
& & B \arrow[uuuu, dashrightarrow, dash] \arrow[ru, "B_{1}"] \arrow[rd, "B_{2}"] \\
& & & (1{,}3)
\end{tikzcd}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

I hope this post was helpful. I wish you a good day and many more hours of success with LaTeX!

Comment: wow, thanks a lot, it works great! sorry for the quality of images, in future i'll try to make it as good-looking as yours. Cheers!

Comment: No problem. I joined this forum to help other people and gain more knowledge. I wish you a lot of luck with your LaTeX projects. If you need any more help, just ask, I'd be honoured to help!